# Using a class as an attribute in another class or just one value?

Tags: object-oriented, php

I have a PHP script which has a group class and a component class. Each group consists of several components. My group has attributes groupName, groupId and componentList. My component has a componentName, a componentId, a componentStatus.
It is necessary to assign a groupId to a component to create it (so the component gets stored in the group with the assigend groupId).

Now my question is:
Should an attribute for component be 'groupId' (which it necessary needs for creation) or should it be the 'group' object itself?

I fear, if I use 'group' it will crash if I want to print my group out because 'group' has componentList as an attribute so it would recursively repeat itself because every single component has its group and every group has its componentList and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem appears to be displaying components and groups, not whether or not a component should have a "group" or "groupId".

These are two separate problems that require separate answers.

So to answer:

> Should an attribute for component be 'groupId' (which it necessary needs for creation) or should it be the 'group' object itself?

If, given a component, you never need more than the groupId, then `groupId` is sufficient. If you need more than the groupId, then you need the entire group as an attribute of a component.

Now, to address this concern:

> I fear, if I use 'group' it will crash if I want to print my group out because 'group' has componentList as an attribute so it would recursively repeat itself because every single component has its group and every group has its componentList and so on.

You need a separate class, or a template that knows not to recursively print the components associated with the group associated with the component you are displaying. Don't create recursive code:

```
<!-- in component.php -->

<h1>
    <?= $component->getName() ?>
    <small><?= $component->getGroup()->getName() ?></small>
</h1>

<?php foreach ($component->getGroup()->getComponents() as $siblingComponent) ?>
    <!-- Don't do this! -->
    <? include('component.php') ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. A developer in my company recommended using 'group' as an attribute. But basically I only need groupId. I didn't even consider your second approach. Thanks for that.